# What JSON RPC commands are suitable for a multi-tenant wallet service?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, multi-signature, litecoin-qt

I'm looking at the JSON-RPC commands available in the QT client so I can create a multi-tenant wallet service on top of it.  In other words, people would sign up for my site and have the ability to create a wallet, with its own address.

One concern I have is that a "change" address would be created and wouldn't go into an account I expect and therefore I need to have a way to manage this in my application.

**Question**

- What JSON RPC commands should (or expressly shouldn't) be used in the above scenario? ... what additional considerations apply?

For example, suppose I want to do a M of N or multisig hosted wallet.  Would those commands "play nicely" with change address?

- Should I export the private key from the wallet, and only import it when it's being used/spent?

In my research I've discovered that  `getaddressesbyaccount` only returns one Base58 address per "text name" in my QT client.  I don't understand the conditions when this will be populated with more than one address, if I can manually make this have more than one address (for testing).

Comment: This seems obvious, but have you looked at the blockchain hosted wallet? http://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api. They specifically exclude some json rpc commands because they're not appropriate for a hosted wallet.

I also think that if you use "sendfrom", then the change goes back to the from account.